# Joomla cache make website's first page really late to open

Tags: caching, joomla, virtuemart

I have an e-shop made with Joomla - Virtuemart.

The issue is that, at the first page, the website starts to open after 20-30seconds you hit the URL.

After discussing it with my hosting provider, they found that **index.php sends for about 20s requests at the file :**

httpdocs/cache/convertECB/86b44edeb1436781d050e4862dd10353-cache-convertECB-bf2c8f06ab151915cd5d7bbef20b70dd.php

Even if i manually delete it, joomla recreates the file and continue to be slow.

In global configuration cache is off.

Any idea, from what is this file coming from and how should i handle the situation?

**UPDATE - CONTENT OF THE PHP FILE**

```
<?php die("Access Denied");?>
#x#a:2:{s:6:"output";s:0:"";s:6:"result";a:32:{s:3:"EUR";s:1:"1";s:3:"USD";s:6:"1.1174";s:3:"JPY";s:6:"116.65";s:3:"BGN";s:6:"1.9558";s:3:"CZK";s:6:"27.067";s:3:"DKK";s:6:"7.4355";s:3:"GBP";s:7:"0.79033";s:3:"HUF";s:6:"315.15";s:3:"PLN";s:6:"4.4490";s:3:"RON";s:6:"4.5390";s:3:"SEK";s:6:"9.3915";s:3:"CHF";s:6:"1.0812";s:3:"NOK";s:6:"9.3798";s:3:"HRK";s:6:"7.5240";s:3:"RUB";s:7:"73.5915";s:3:"TRY";s:6:"3.2804";s:3:"AUD";s:6:"1.5212";s:3:"BRL";s:6:"3.8943";s:3:"CAD";s:6:"1.4530";s:3:"CNY";s:6:"7.3593";s:3:"HKD";s:6:"8.6715";s:3:"IDR";s:8:"14970.82";s:3:"ILS";s:6:"4.3228";s:3:"INR";s:7:"75.2010";s:3:"KRW";s:7:"1315.79";s:3:"MXN";s:7:"21.1845";s:3:"MYR";s:6:"4.5885";s:3:"NZD";s:6:"1.5899";s:3:"PHP";s:6:"51.899";s:3:"SGD";s:6:"1.5116";s:3:"THB";s:6:"39.455";s:3:"ZAR";s:7:"17.2240";}}
```

Answer (score 0):

ECB is virtuemart currency conversion rates file. That file is downloaded 3 to 4 times daily depending on your settings. It is in cache ditetory and updated with new file names.

EDIT

You have to uninstall the module as by disabling it will still download xml conversion file. Login to administrator and then go to `Control panel, Extensions - Install/Uninstall`. Search and select "mod_virtuemart_currencies" now click on the uninstall button at the top.

Comment: How can I disable it?  We have only one currency at the eshop

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have more than one currency (maybe you have one product priced with another currency - once this is the case, the ECB will automatically be triggered). In any case, the fact that it's waiting 20-30 seconds means that it's timing out on something. Maybe it's trying to open a URL that has the IP of your website banned (this is very possible, and we had the exact scenario with one of our clients before).

If you can provide us with the contents of the cache file that is being called by your `index.php` file, maybe we can be of more help.